# Getting all bids from each Header bidding partners

Tags: prebid.js

We are implementing some header bidding partners on our wrapper using prebid. Is it possible to get all bids from each ssp.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re asking about demand, this is dependent on each SSP. For example there may be a segment pixel or placement in one SSP that will always give you a $10 bid, but that wouldnt apply to the other SSPs.

If your asking about getting data on all the bids, you may want to check out pbjs.getBidResponses() which returns an object with the ad units and bids

Heres a sample response from [`pbjs.getBidResponses()`](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html#module_pbjs.getBidResponses) which can then be used however you'd need that data:

```
{
    "div-id-one": {
        "bids": [
            {
                "bidderCode": "appnexus",
                "width": 970,
                "height": 250,
                "statusMessage": "Bid available",
                "adId": "1293a95bb3e9615",
                "mediaType": "banner",
                "creative_id": 77765220,
                "cpm": 0.7826,
                "adUrl": "https://...",
                "requestId": "57f961f3-a32b-45df-a180-9d5e53fb9070",
                "responseTimestamp": 1513707536256,
                "requestTimestamp": 1513707535321,
                "bidder": "appnexus",
                "adUnitCode": "div-id-one",
                "timeToRespond": 935,
                "pbLg": "0.50",
                "pbMg": "0.70",
                "pbHg": "0.78",
                "pbAg": "0.75",
                "pbDg": "0.78",
                "pbCg": "0.78",
                "size": "970x250",
                "adserverTargeting": {
                    "hb_bidder": "appnexus",
                    "hb_adid": "1293a95bb3e9615",
                    "hb_pb": "0.78",
                    "hb_size": "970x250"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "div-id-two": {
        "bids": []
    }
}
```

Theres also a great example on prebid.org on how to output this to console.table that could be helpful as well:

```
var responses = pbjs.getBidResponses();
var output = [];
for (var adunit in responses) {
    if (responses.hasOwnProperty(adunit)) {
        var bids = responses[adunit].bids;
        for (var i = 0; i < bids.length; i++) {
            var b = bids[i];
            output.push({
                'adunit': adunit, 'adId': b.adId, 'bidder': b.bidder,
                'time': b.timeToRespond, 'cpm': b.cpm, 'msg': b.statusMessage
            });
        }
    }
}
if (output.length) {
    if (console.table) {
        console.table(output);
    } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
            console.log(output[j]);
        }
    }
} else {
    console.warn('NO prebid responses');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a chrome extensions called *Prebid helper* that do the same as console snippet but with less clicks.

However that is useful for initial setup debug. If you need to gather aggregated data on all demand partners - bids, timeouts, wins etc. You will need to run third party wrapper analytics or use analytics adapter. It's not free but it usually is priced depending on your load on the analytics server. For example https://headbidder.net/pricing

Answer (score 0):

Try out the Chrome Extension called **Adwizard**. It's been built to debug prebid setups. Shows you all networks and bids per adunit. CPM and Size included.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adwizard/kndnhcfdajkaickocacghchhpieogbjh/?ref=stackoverflow